# add views programmatically on DialogFragment leaves empty space

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-databinding

Given I have a custom dialog class that extends from `DialogFragment`.
Suppose I have dialog that shows Doctor information in it, it also has booking schedules that consist of String ArrayList which shows the available date.

In my layout I have prepared a placeholder for the image, name, and also I have prepared a vertical Linear Layout where I will addViews programmatically of ArrayList from the Java Class.

I am looping the List to addView to the LinearLayout

```
    private Doctor doctor; // it has doctor.schedule = ArrayList<String>

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutSearchDoctorDialogBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.layout_search_doctor_dialog, container, true);
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        binding.layoutSchedule.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        for (Schedule schedule : doctor.schedule) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_schedule, null);
            TextView textDays = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_days);
            TextView textHours = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_hours);
            textDays.setText(schedule.day);
            textHours.setText(schedule.hours);
            binding.layoutSchedule.addView(view,
                    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
        binding.setViewModel(new SearchDoctorDialogViewModel(doctor));
        binding.btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((SearchDoctorView) getActivity()).checkRecords(doctor.phoneNumber);
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
```

Here is my Dialog Layout **R.layout.layout_search_doctor_dialog**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16dp">

    <com.bloonerd.rspondokindah.custom.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_60dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.image}"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="Michael Jackson"
        android:text="@{viewModel.doctorName}"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp"/>

    <!-- Linear Layout below is where I will addViews -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_schedule"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also this is what I am adding to the LinearLayout addView **R.layout.item_schedule**

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_days"
        style="@style/Width0HeightWrapStyle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_small"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_hours"
        style="@style/WrapContentStyle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_small"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I debug it, it shows that I am looping **doctor.schedule** and adding it to the view. But it only shows the first index of the String ArrayList.
However it leaves empty spaces in the LinearLayout that looks like the String ArrayList were already added but hidden.

Moreover, after I check with `uiautomatorviewer` there is only **one** child view inside `layout_schedule` LinearLayout

I realize this is only specific for DialogFragment, In RecyclerView I can show the list just fine

**How it is now:** ---------------------------------------------> **What I want**

```
__________           __________            __________
|        |  ----->   |[item 1]|   ----->   |[item 1]|
----------   Loop    |        |            |[item 2]|
                     |        |            |[item 3]|
                     |        |            |[item 4]|
                     |        |            |[item 5]|
                     ----------            ----------
```

Comment: Use ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT for the height when adding the inflated view to layoutSchedule.

Comment: ohoho, you saved my day ^o^